# google-apps-script google calendar null event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I don't understand why "event" always returns null, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and haven't been able to find anything in the docs.

```
var cal_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com";
var start = new Date();
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal_id);
var end = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 3)); 
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal_id);
var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end);
var event_id = events[0].getId();
var event = calendar.getEventById(event_id)
```

Comment: What is the value of `event_id`?

Comment: "2515cbb2ddf445798634cc45b9113551-g5128581" I redacted part of the string for privacy.

Comment: @Sohil What is the value of cal_id? The one in my code snippet is clearly a dummy id.

Comment: It seems like you're using a personal calendar, the code snippet above was using a calendar that I subscribed to. You grab the ID from the calendar settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by using `var event = events[0];` and not using `getId()` at all. The final code looks similar to this this:

```
var cal_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com";
var start = new Date();
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal_id);
var end = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 3)); 
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal_id);
var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end);
var event = events[0];
```